# Select option con PHP

Tags: php, html, select, options

Soy principiante con todo lo respecto a  programación orientada a objetos. Resulta que tengo un `select` para seleccionar un cliente de la base de datos y que me muestre su informción y lo he resuelto con un script de `changefunction`, pero necesito me saque de ahí solo el `id` del cliente para registro en otra tabla de la base de datos.

muestro mi codigo:

```html
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <h3>Facturado a:</h3>
    <br>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <strong>Cliente:</strong>
        <?php
            $consulta="SELECT * FROM user ORDER by name_user ASC";
            $bd->consulta($consulta);
        ?>
        <select class="form-control" name="cliente" id="consulCliente">
            <option value=""><p>Seleccione el Cliente...</p></option>
            <?php
                while ($fila = $bd->mostrar_registros()) {
                    $cliente = 0;
                    $nombre = 0;
            ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $cliente=$fila->name_user; ?>
                        <br>
                        <b>Empresa.</b> <?php echo $fila->empresa; ?>.
                        <br>
                        <b>CC/Nit.</b> <?php echo $fila->ci_user; ?>.
                        <br>
                        <b>Telefono:</b> <?php echo $fila->phone_user; ?>. 
                        <br>
                        <b>Direccion:</b><?php echo $fila->direccion; ?>.
                        <br>
                        <b>Email:</b> <?php echo $fila->mail_user; ?>">
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $nombre=$fila->name_user; ?> <?php echo $fila->last_name_user; ?>
                        </p>
                    </option>
            <?php
                    $cliente;
                    $nombre;
                }
            ?>
        </select> 
        <script>
            $( "select" ).change(function () {
                document.getElementById("consulta").innerHTML = "" + document.getElementById("consulCliente").value;
            });
        </script>
    </ul>
    <div class="col-xs-10" >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <div class="list-unstyled" id="consulta"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Necesito capturar ese `id` de la función y sacarlo para enviarlo al `SQL INSERT` y agregarlo a su correspondiente tabla.

Comment: Nada más tienes que cambiar esto `<option value="<?php echo $cliente=$fila->name_user; ?>` por algo así: `<option value="<?php echo $cliente=$fila->id_user; ?>` suponiendo que `id_user` es el nombre de la columna que tiene el id. Luego, al enviar el formulario podrás recuperar por POST el valor mediante `$_POST['cliente']` OJO, aquí se usa `cliente` porque ese es el `name` de tu etiqueta `select` que contiene los `option`.

Comment: :( ya lo probé pero me guarda un cero, debido a que me toma todos los datos que contiene el `option`, es decir como utiliza la `function change` todos campos de la fila de la consulta. debido a eso le agregue la variable `$cliente` pues para que solo me tomara el `$user = utf8_decode($_POST['cliente']);` ese es el que inserto a la tabla. que estoy haciendo mal...por fa.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu código. Dentro de este bloque: `$( "select" ).change(function () {` deberías más bien lanzar la petición Ajax, mandando el valor del option que se seleccionó. No sé de qué sirve esto realmente `document.getElementById("consulta").innerHTML = "" + document.getElementById("consulCliente").value;` de cara  a lo que quieres lograr ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en el select el value es `name_user`, podrías meter todo dentro de un formulario com un method `POST` y en el action haces la sentencia y declaras una variable con el valor `$var = $_POST['consulCliente']` y así tomas el value del select y luego ya en la consulta haces el insert con la variable

Comment: Mira [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida, trata de agregar un ejemplo de cómo lo harías para solucionar el problema en concreto.

Comment: si claro, podría cambiar ese name_user por id_user ya que es la llave principal, pero no sabría como sacarlo, seria posible elaborar un ejemplo tan pronto puedas pues para asi poder entender aun mejor. gracias

Comment: Esto es incorrecto: `$_POST['consulCliente']` **los datos del POST se recuperan usando la etiqueta `name` de los elementos, no la etiqueta `id`**, si se otorgó `cliente` como `name` del select, entonces debe ser `$_POST['cliente']`

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres mostrar la información del cliente y enviar su id, tienes que tener esa información separada, para eso puedes colocar la información en un data-set, la puedes colocar separada por barras bajas, luego cuando obtienes la información con jquery puedes dividirla y darle formato.

Así se veria el código:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-4">
    <h3>Facturado a:</h3>
    <br>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <strong>Cliente:</strong>
        <select class="form-control" name="cliente" id="consulCliente">
            <option value="" selected disabled><p>Seleccione el Cliente...</p></option>
            <option value="1" data-info="Empresa1_1234_67737333_C/25#11_hola1@gmail.com">Nombre1 Apellido1</option>
            <option value="1" data-info="Empresa2_1234_77737333_C/25#12_hola2@gmail.com">Nombre2 Apellido2</option>
        </select> 
        <script>
            $( "#consulCliente" ).change(function () {
                var info = $( "#consulCliente option:selected" ).data('info').split('_');
                var texto = "<br><b>Empresa.</b> "+info[0]+
                    "<br><b>CC/Nit.</b> "+ info[1]+
                    "<br><b>Telefono:</b> "+info[2]+ 
                    "<br><b>Direccion:</b> "+info[3]+
                    "<br><b>Email:</b> "+info[4];
                $("#consulta").html(texto);
            });
        </script>
    </ul>
    <div class="col-xs-10" >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <div class="list-unstyled" id="consulta"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

y asi es como deberias ponerlo en tu pagina:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <h3>Facturado a:</h3>
    <br>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <strong>Cliente:</strong>
        <?php
            $consulta="SELECT * FROM user ORDER by name_user ASC";
            $bd->consulta($consulta);
        ?>
        <select class="form-control" name="cliente" id="consulCliente">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione el Cliente...</option>
            <?php
                while ($fila = $bd->mostrar_registros()) {
            ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $fila->id_user; ?>"
                        data-info="<?php echo $fila->empresa.'_'.$fila->ci_user.'_'.$fila->phone_user.'_'.$fila->direccion.'_'.$fila->mail_user; ?>">
                        <?php echo $nombre=$fila->name_user; ?> <?php echo $fila->last_name_user; ?>
                    </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select> 
        <script>
            $( "#consulCliente" ).change(function () {
                var info = $( "#consulCliente option:selected" ).data('info').split('_');
                var texto = "<br><b>Empresa.</b> "+info[0]+
                    ".<br><b>CC/Nit.</b> "+ info[1]+
                    "<br><b>Telefono:</b> "+info[2]+ 
                    "<br><b>Direccion:</b> "+info[3]+
                    "<br><b>Email:</b> "+info[4];
                $("#consulta").html(texto);
        </script>
    </ul>
    <div class="col-xs-10" >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <div class="list-unstyled" id="consulta"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

avisame si se te complica alguna parte.

Comment: solucionado, muchas gracias

Comment: hermano solucionado...muchas gracias :)

Comment: de nada, ¿hermano? ┐(´•_•`)┌